# What is a shortest way or LINQ query to remove non consecutive rows from list of grouped rows?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Background: I am using Linq to get the data. Wrote below query to get  `List<List<InboxProcessingDto>>` , now I want to remove record who don't have  consecutive sequenceId in each `List<InboxProcessingDto>`.
`List<InboxProcessingDto>` will be always sorted.

Linq Query:

```
_context.Inboxes
                .Join(_context.InboxProcessingOffsets, x => x.SequenceSource, y => y.Source, (x, y) => new InboxProcessingDto { Inbox = x, InboxProcessingOffset = y })
                .Where(i => (i.Inbox.Status == InboxStatus.New ))
                .Take(100)
                .ToList()
                .GroupBy(i => i.Inbox. SequenceSource)
                .Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(i => i.Inbox.SequenceId))
                .ToListAsync();
```

Above query gives me data like below screenshot:
[image: Data from above query]

List at [0] contains 4 objects of InboxProcessingDto and this dto has sequenceID, list[0] might have objects who don't have consecutive sequence id eg. 22, 23,27,28
from this list I want to remove 2 objects who has sequenceId 27,28

as we can see in screenshot next list from List<List> contains 5 objects of InboxProcessingDto and this dto has sequenceID, it might have objects who don't have consecutive sequence id eg. 2, 3,17,28,29
from this list I want to remove 3 objects who has sequenceId 17,28,29

Comment: Show an example of your input and desired output.

Comment: Won't all of them have non-sequential sequenceId once you remove some? And which is considered non-sequential, the one before or after a gap?

Comment: Hi Robert, NetMage

Apologies for late response, I have update the description I hope it will help.
Waiting for your response.
thank you!

Comment: What is `_context`? (I.e. which ORM and which version is this?). Either way, this is going to be an in-memory operation after getting the data. You won't be able to do it in LINQ that translates to SQL.